# React js issue on iOS browser

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am developing react for my web apps.. Currently im facing some issues that only happening on iOS browser. Everything works well on android browser and desktop browser. Problem such as some content not visible after navigating into another page, cannot typing on textbox. Do u guys have any idea how to fix this? Thank you so much.

Comment: could you provide a sample where it works on other browsers but fails in ios safari?

Comment: @harun im sorry i cant provide example for you because its still on our development server. Imagine if you have a list of data and then theres a button that will show a modal. If i close that modal, somehow my list become not visible on iOS, but everythings good in another browser. Everything looks good too when i inspected the element

Answer (score 0):

for textbox issue you can check if there is `-webkit-user-select:none` property assigned then remove this property and textboxes will start working as expected

Hope this helps you!

Comment: Theres not `webkit-user-select:none` exist on the code. its working as expected but sometime it doesnt work correctly..